# Simplifying a radical with complex fractions

Tags: exponentiation, radicals, fractions

So I understand to simplify this:

$$
\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{|\frac{1}{2t^3}|\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^6} - 1}}
$$

I can just multiply

$$
\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{|\frac{1}{2t^3}|\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^6} - 1}} \cdot\frac{2t^4}{2t^4}
$$

and get

$$
\frac{-3}{t\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^6} - 1}}
$$

But how do you simplify further getting rid of the complex fraction inside the radical?

Comment: I think you still need absolute value bars.  Consider $t=-1$, you will see there is a small difference.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt {4t^6}$

Comment: Can you walk me through that Doug? I'm just not seeing how it works out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{|\frac{1}{2t^3}|\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^6} - 1}} \frac{\sqrt {4t^6}}{\sqrt{4t^6}}$ first step will be to get rid of the fraction inside the radical.  Note that ${\sqrt{4t^6}} = |2t^3|$

$\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}|2t^3|}{|\frac{1}{2t^3}|\sqrt{1 - 4t^6}} \frac{\sqrt {1-4t^6}}{\sqrt{1-4t^6}}$  Then we get the radical outside of the numerator.

$
\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}|2t^3|\sqrt {1-4t^6}}{|\frac{1}{2t^3}|(1 - 4t^6)} \frac{|2t^3|}{|2t^3|}$  Now I am taking on what you did in the first step.  I think it is best to attack the messiest parts first.

$
\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}(4t^6)\sqrt {1-4t^6}}{(1 - 4t^6)}\\
\frac{-6t^2\sqrt {1-4t^6}}{(1 - 4t^6)}$

Answer (score 2):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{\left|\frac{1}{2t^3}\right|\sqrt{\frac{1}{4t^6} - 1}}&=\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{\left|\frac{1}{2t^3}\right|\sqrt{\frac{1-4t^6}{4t^6}}}
\\&=\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{\left|\frac{1}{2t^3}\right|\frac{\sqrt{1-4t^6}}{\sqrt{4t^6}}}
\\&=\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{\frac{1}{2\left|t\right|^3}\frac{\sqrt{1-4t^6}}{2|t|^3}}
\\&=\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}}{\frac{\sqrt{1-4t^6}}{4t^6}}
\\&=\frac{\frac{-3}{2t^4}\times 4t^6}{\sqrt{1-4t^6}}
\\&=-\frac{6t^2}{\sqrt{1-4t^6}}.
\end{align}
$$